How to write a function that calculates percentage multiplicatively in Google Sheets



Column A
Column B




A
5%


B
8%


C
10%


D
10%


E
10%


F
10%


G
20%


H
35%


Base
100


Total
?



Given the table above, I need a function that calculates the percentage multiplicatively.
so something like this:

((100 * .05) + 100) = 105
((105 * .08) + 105) = 113.4
((113.4 * .10) + 113.4) = 124.74
etc, etc


REDUCE is the function you need for this:
=REDUCE(B10,B2:B9,LAMBDA(a,c,a*c+a))


If you want to return all the intermediate results, replace REDUCE with SCAN
=SCAN(B10,B2:B9,LAMBDA(a,c,a*c+a))


